# Retrieving string extract using Substring and Charindex

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have asked this question before. I have multiple different File Names and I have a field called 'File Name' and I wanted to extract 'H and A ADQ' and 'Vita' string and put it in another field called [Query Name]. As shown below.

```
File Name ||
N:\Health\Local\Information\Tec\IS\Exports\MM\ADQ star pu\H and A ADQ April.csv
N:\Health\Local\Information\Tec\IS\Exports\MM\ADQ star pu\Vita April.csv
```

I just need the 'H and A ADQ' and 'Vita'.

I have tried this script:

```
Update [MM].[dbo].[Star]
SET [Query Name]=REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([File Name]),12,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([File Name]))-1)  ,1,CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(REVERSE([File Name]),1,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE([File Name]))-1)))),'.csv','')
```

From tweaking the script I just managed to get 'H and A AD' instead of 'H and A ADQ'.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: rather than open a new question for the same thing, why not edit your original question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740643/substring-and-charindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update [MM].[dbo].[Star]
SET [Query Name]= 
    SUBSTRING([File Name], LEN([File Name]) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([File Name])) + 2, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([File Name])) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([File Name])) - 1)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a87f/1)

Comment: Is there a way to right this as an expression in Derived Column.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I want this process to be done using a Derived Column.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Do have an example or any further description for what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry I have been very vague. I wanted to carry out this task in SSIS using Derived Column.

Comment: I have a filename called: N:\Health\Local\Information\Tec\IS\Exports\MM\ADQ star pu\PPI low cost excl Hpylori April.csv. But the method doesn't seem to work when running the script in Execute SQL Task but as a normal script running as a query it does any ideas? Thanks